# Templates render properly on deployment server but TemplateDoesNotExist error on runserver

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-templates, uwsgi

I have a project structure like this

```
mainproject
├── manage.py
├── mainproject
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── mainproject
│   │       └── index.html
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── app
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── forms.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── templates
    │   └── app
    │       ├── index.html
    │       └── abc.html
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.py
```

Now in my settings.py I have

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {   
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['mainproject/templates', 'app/templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

When I use this on main domain on my deployment server, (deployed using nginx and uwsgi), it works all well.

I am able to access mainproject's index at `domain.com` and app's index at `domain.com/app`

But when using `runserver`, only `domain.com:8000/app` works and `domain.com:8000` gives error `TemplateDoesNotExist at /`.

Why so and how this could be fixed?

Template loader postmortem:

```
 Using engine django:
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /home/mohit/mainproject/templates/mainproject/index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /home/mohit/app/templates/mainproject/index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/mohit/Env/mainproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/mainproject/index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/mohit/Env/mainproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/mainproject/index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/mohit/mainproject/app/templates/mainproject/index.html (Source does not exist)
```

If I change `DIRS` line in `TEMPLATES` in settings.py and make it

```
'DIRS': ['mainproject/mainproject/templates', 'app/templates'],
```

Then it works on runserver and doesnt work on deployment server.

Comment: Try using relative paths in your settings. http://www.morethanseven.net/2009/02/11/django-settings-tip-setting-relative-paths/

Comment: Your templates folder paths would not be same in development  and production servers, As commented above its always better to use relative paths

Comment: Thanks guys, that worked. If you can post that as an answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments by xtranophilist and Amar, I used relative path as follows and it worked:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
....
```

Then in template dirs:

```
'DIRS': [BASE_DIR + '/mainproject/templates']
```